# Forcing a secondary sort on a DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Is there an approach for programatically applying WPF `DataGrid` sorting based on multiple properties?

I have a multi-column `DataGrid` which contains a single column which I always want to be in alphabetical order within groupings of values when other columns are sorted.

All custom sort implementations I've seen use a `IComparer`, but this only provides the values in the single column it's associated with.

For example, if we have the following two columns of unsorted data:

- `A`  `1`
- `D`  `2`
- `C`  `2`
- `B`  `1`

If we apply sorting to the second column, the first column becomes arbitrarily sorted within each grouping:

- `A`  `1`
- `B`  `1`
- `D`  `2`
- `C`  `2`

What I am looking for is for within any groups of identical values in the second column, the first column is alphabetised:

- `A`  `1`
- `B`  `1`
- `C`  `2`
- `D`  `2`

Is there an alternative to `IComparer` which exposes the full model?

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6469303/sort-on-multiple-columns-in-wpf-datagrid

Comment: That may apply initial multi-column sorting but doesn't preserve the sorting behaviour after users subsequently sort columns.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43338043/sort-a-wpf-datagrid-by-a-value-within-a-group?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked into SortMemberPath?

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Some Caption"  Width="200"
        CanUserSort="True"
        Binding="{Binding SomeDataField}" 
        SortMemberPath="OtherNonShowingField"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

So if you are listing data from a List
or from a DataTable via its DataColumn reference, you could always add another field or column that has the combined A + B parts in that field.  So even if you don't show the column, it can be used as the basis of a sort.

Since I do not know of another way to utilize the SortMemberPath to do both an ascending AND descending in the same, I wrote a function that you can try to use in your code.  I called it NegativeString, thus a reversal of alphabetical order and numbers.  Anything else is "as-is".

```
private static string UpperCase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
private static string LowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnoprqstuvwxyz";
private static string Numbers = "0123456789";
public string NegativeString( string incoming )
{
    // take incoming string, put into a character array
    var inB = incoming.ToCharArray();
    var outStr = "";
    for( var i= 0; i < inB.Length; i++ )
    {
        // So, if I Look for "A" in the upper-case string, it is found
        // in position 0, so I want the character 0 from the end
        // which is the letter Z and vice-versa.
        var atPos = UpperCase.IndexOf(inB[i]);
        if (atPos > -1)
            outStr += UpperCase.Substring(UpperCase.Length - atPos - 1, 1);
        else
        {
            // if not upper case, then look for lower
            atPos = LowerCase.IndexOf(inB[i]);
            if (atPos > -1)
                outStr += LowerCase.Substring(LowerCase.Length - atPos - 1, 1);
            else
            {
                // if not lower, try numbers
                atPos = Numbers.IndexOf(inB[i]);
                if (atPos > -1)
                    outStr += Numbers.Substring(Numbers.Length - atPos - 1, 1);
                else
                    // anything else comes along as-is
                    outStr += inB[i];
            }
        }
    }

    return outStr;
}
```

So, a new property on your class could be something like

```
public string YourMultiSortProperty
{  get { return NormalField + NegativeString( OtherField ); }}
```

Comment: Excellent idea. Simple and elegant. Works well, thanks!

Comment: @nullPainter, also works well on things such as date/time fields where you want to show in mm-dd-yyyy format (for example), but want the actual sort based on the DATETIME, not the character representation as displayed.

Comment: Any hints on combining string fields that should be one ascending and the other descending?

Comment: @DanielMöller, what example of alternate sorting.  Please create your own post, show some sample of the data you have and how you would like to alternate the sorting and the basis of ascending vs descending.  Then, let me know, and others too can see and reply.

Comment: A simple equivalent of `collection.OrderBy(someRule).ThenByDescending(anotherRule)`.

Comment: @DanielMöller, I understand, but f your datagrid is based on some listed source, it shows the records in the default order it has.  If you specify the SortMemberPath, that wins.  So, if you QUERY the data in the alternative order, and do NOT use the sort member path, that might work for you.

Comment: Yes, there are alternative solutions, I was just wondering, 100% related to your answer (using a combined field for SortMemberPath), if there is some simple way to combine two string fields like that.

Comment: @DanielMöller, The only thing i can think of is creating a function that takes a string and reverses its ordinal context.  Ex: var normal = 'ABCDEFG... abcdefg..." and then, for each byte in an array from this, find the LAST corresponding to return back a string.  Such as ABC would return ZYX, but similar with upper and lower case.  Hope this gives you something to chew on.

Comment: @DanielMöller, check revision showing a negative string function to reverse context that may work for you.